# Restoring an 64 SQL server 2005 backup to a 32 bit installation

Tags: backup, sql-server-2005, 32bit-64bit

I am under the impression that this cannot be done, but would love to know if it can. And if so, why?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detaching a Microsoft SQL 32bit database and attaching it to a 64bit server.](http://serverfault.com/questions/101748/detaching-a-microsoft-sql-32bit-database-and-attaching-it-to-a-64bit-server) - question is worded differently but same answers apply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is possible the backup files are the same regardless of architecture.